# CSS navigation bootstrap on mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have dropdown menu on hover, submenu is over the main menu, but I want insert after parent menu and do not hide another parents menus.

mobile menu:

[image]

on hover:

[image]

what I want:

[image]

```
  <div class="main-menu" id="menu">
    <ul class="menu upper-2">
      <li>
        <a id="m">Nav1</a>
        <div class="dropdown row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" id="dropdown">
            <div class="categories">
              <ul>
              <a href="#">Sub1</a>
              <a href="#">Sub2</a>
              <a href="#">Sub3</a>
              <a href="#">Sub4</a>
              <a href="#">Sub5</a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>          

      <li>
        <a>Nav2</a>
        <div class="dropdown row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" id="dropdown">
            <div class="categories">
              <a href="#">Sub1</a>
              <a href="#">Sub2</a>
              <a href="#">Sub3</a>
              <a href="#">Sub4</a>
              <a href="#">Sub5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>


      <li>
        <a>Nav3</a>
        <div class="dropdown row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" id="dropdown">
            <div class="categories">
              <a href="#">Sub1</a>
              <a href="#">Sub2</a>
              <a href="#">Sub3</a>
              <a href="#">Sub4</a>
              <a href="#">Sub5</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I think my problem is in "dropdown" class 
I think my problem is in "dropdown" class 
I think my problem is in "dropdown" class

CSS:

```
header nav ul.menu > li > .dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -23px;
}

header nav ul.menu > li:hover > .dropdown {
  padding: 14px 12px;
}

header nav .dropdown .categories {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -ms-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
}

header nav .dropdown .categories a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-transform: initial;
    position: relative;
}
```

I think my problem is in "dropdown" class 
I think my problem is in "dropdown" class

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or runnable code snippet?

Comment: which version for used the bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap's grid classes which have **left-padding** & **right-padding** of **15px**.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" id="dropdown">
```

So you should give this element a class:

```
<div class="className col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" id="dropdown">
```

And inside your stylesheet you should compensate this like so:

```
.className {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Also you are using same id on multiple elements. ID-s **must be unique**.

From w3.org:

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.

Use classes instead like so:

```
<div class="className col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
```

More about ID-s: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute